# Highcharts | Making multiple y axis scales

Tags: highcharts

Im trying to make this chart have multiple Y Axes, all of which have different values and tick intervals. Like Signal Strength be on a scale of 0%-100%, Temperature 0F-100F and Main Power be 0V to 25V but cant seem to figure it out. Here's my jFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/0k5k8ygz/

Code:

```js
function createChart() {

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis 
            labels: {
                format: '{value}°F',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
                }
            },
            opposite: true

        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Main Power',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} volts',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            }

        }, { // Tertiary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Signal Strength',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} %',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent',
                showInNavigator: true
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2,
            split: true
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });
}


$.each(names, function(i, name) {

    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=' + name.toLowerCase() + '-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {

        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data
        };

        // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
        // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
        seriesCounter += 1;

        if (seriesCounter === names.length) {
            createChart();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So what's the actual question (be specific)?

Comment: Sorry, I cant figure out how to add numerical values to all 3 Y axis scales. On the right side of the chart, Main Power and Signal Strength are both blank. How would I go about making them have numerical values? Main power being on a scale of 0 to 24, Signal Strength being on a scale of 0% to 100%

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you add some data to each of the y-axes, they will get tick marks automatically. You assign data to a specific y-axis using the `series.yAxis` index:

```
seriesOptions[i] = {
    name: name,
    data: data,
    yAxis: i,
};
```

If you also want to specify a valid range for the y-axes, you can set `min` and `max` on each individual axis:

```
...
labels: {
    format: '{value} volts',
},
min: 0,
max: 25,
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0k5k8ygz/5/

Comment: Thanks Sphinxxx! This answered my question!